# Teach Tessearact with training images and text

Tags: windows, visual-studio, command-line, tesseract

I am new in [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/list)

I am working on a Windows OS. 
I want to teach tesseract to use my own 80 chars of font. Nothing else. I read this explanation:

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3

But I cannot find a executable file called "training". Also there is no file called "text2image" because it is written in other forums.

Can you explain how to get the needed tesseract library if my font on Windows is local installed, I have a tiff file ready and the training text ready.

> training/text2image --text="C:\projects\scanner\training_text.txt" --outputbase=ocr.ocrb.exp0 --font='Courier New' --fonts_dir="C:\Windows\Fonts"

[image: current tesseract directory]

Comment: text2image is tool from tesseract-ocr 3.04 version.

Comment: Thank you. How to train tesseract in current version?

Comment: Current version is 3.04 version. What is not clear on instructions https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract ?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to train tesseract would be to use a third party software like jTessBoxEditor (http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html). Even if it's not using the latest version of tesseract, the generated files are compatible.

You'll just have to select your font and your training text and it'll generate all the needed files. It'll also allow you to easily check the generated box are correct.

Comment: I found out, that I need to use https://code.google.com/export-to-github/start-export/serak-tesseract-trainer?code=73561014ed6a327d0728 to train data. Anyway, it will recognize some chars as "(" even if there was no time any train of this char. My char-set has no "(". How to limit the chars to needed chars?